# Index was outside on the bounds of array error on c# log in with SQL

Tags: c#, sql, xml

Hi i have a login which connects to a server string and executes this when the login button is pushed. It returns the invalid error if the user and password is not stored on the database but it throws a "Index was outside on the bounds of array" error if they are on the database. How would i fix this??
Thanks

My connection string is located in my appconfig file, could the problem be in there?

##########FORM WINDOWS AFTER LOGIN BUTTON CLICK

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SqlConnection con = Program.GetConnection;
SqlDataReader dr = null;
try
    {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName='" +
            txtName.Text + "'AND Password='" + textpassword.Text + "'", con);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                Program.UserLoginName = dr.GetString(3);
                this.Close();
            }
            else

                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username & Password!");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

#######PROGRAM.CS FILE

```
Using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;  

namespace FrontEndV1
{
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Login());
    }
    public static SqlConnection GetConnection
    {
        get
        {
            string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FrontEndV1Connection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            return con;
        }
    }
    public static string UserLoginName { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: -1 To not responding. How many columns in  the **Users** table?

Comment: @AVD : I believe this is not right to downvote user in such a case, it was seen "18 mins ago" accordingly to SO stat.. I believe you can be in the same situation when posted question and sidetracked for a while, this is not a reason to downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that mistake lays here:  `dr.GetString(3);` try to change 3 to 2. Numeration begins from 0 in arrays.

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
Program.UserLoginName = dr.GetString(3);
```

You're getting a field whose index is greater than returned fields count.
You must use an index between 0 and dr.FieldCount-1.

Or you can use `dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal(desired_field_name))`: this is better (even if it needs more instructions) because you could swap returning order (maybe you need to change your query) without losing functionality.

Comment: @Johan: do you think now it's better? :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't say *where* the error is thrown, but I suspect this line:

```
Program.UserLoginName = dr.GetString(3);
```

Would throw the error if the query returns any fewer than 4 columns.

Also, this is vulnerable to Sql injection. Use a stored proc or parameterised query.

Answer (score 0):

i think you only have three columns. The index of the 3rd column is 2, so change this line

`Program.UserLoginName = dr.GetString(3);`

to

`Program.UserLoginName = dr.GetString(2);`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not debug the application? If you can do then try to locate from where the exception is being thrown. As suggested by Marco and other user if you notice exception when executing `dr.GetString(3)` then problem lies there. Try using correct column ordinal, or use `SELECT Column1, Column2, ..., ColumnN FROM Table` so that you know exactly which ordinal to specify.

Answer (score 0):

Bad coding:

1. using `select *`, you should use the names of the columns
2. using indexes to retrieve values in a row, you should use the actual column name returned

If the above would have been applied there would be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had The Same error using SQL Server Express 2014 with Login Stored Procedure from 3 different tables, I was really confused what was goin on, but finally found that I had more columns Selected from One Table then other two

> sometimes its the logic behind it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).